# Eliminate works on small system of Equations, but fails on big ones

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am trying to calculate the Hamiltonian of a system in terms of momenta. When applying the Eliminate function on a small toy system it works as expected
`Eliminate[{A == B + CC, CC == Q + A}, {CC}]`
(I get meaningful output)
However if I try to enter the whole system of equations for the Hamiltonian and try to eliminate the dx, dy variables I just get True as output which makes no sense.

```
Eliminate[{H == P1 d\[Tau] + P2 dx + P3 dy + P4 d\[Phi] + P5 d\[Tau] - 
L[\[Tau], x, y, \[Phi], \[Psi], d\[Tau], dx, dy, d\[Phi], d\[Psi]],
P1 == D[L[\[Tau], x, y, \[Phi], \[Psi], d\[Tau], dx, dy, d\[Phi], d\[Psi]], d\[Tau]],
P2 == D[L[\[Tau], x, y, \[Phi], \[Psi], d\[Tau], dx, dy, d\[Phi], d\[Psi]], dx],
P3 == D[L[\[Tau], x, y, \[Phi], \[Psi], d\[Tau], dx, dy, d\[Phi], d\[Psi]], dy],
P4 == D[L[\[Tau], x, y, \[Phi], \[Psi], d\[Tau], dx, dy, d\[Phi], d\[Psi]], d\[Phi]],
P5 == D[L[\[Tau], x, y, \[Phi], \[Psi], d\[Tau], dx, dy, d\[Phi], d\[Psi]], d\[Psi]]},
    {d\[Tau], dx, dy, d\[Phi], d\[Psi]}]
```

In this example L is some arbitrary defined function like

```
L[x_, y_, z_] := x dx + y dz
```

Real function is somewhat complicated, but example still holds. Does anybody have a valid explanation for why this is happening?

P.S. tried using solve and other method to no success. This seem like the type of thing that we should be able to do right?

Edit:

The full form of the Lagrangian is:

```
L [\[Tau]_, x_, y_, \[Phi]_, \[Psi]_, d\[Tau]_, dx_, dy_, d\[Phi]_, d\[Psi]_] := (d\[Tau] +  ((\[Alpha] - x) (1 - y))/(2 \[Alpha]) d\[Phi] + ((\[Beta] - x) (1 + y))/(2 \[Beta]) d\[Psi])^2 + \[Rho]/(4 \[CapitalDelta]1) dx^2 + \[Rho]/\[CapitalDelta]2  1/(4 (1 - y^2)) dy^2 + \[CapitalDelta]1/\[Rho] ((1 - y)/(2 \[Alpha]) d\[Phi] + (1 + y)/(2 \[Beta]) d\[Psi])^2 + (\[CapitalDelta]2 (1 - y) (1 + y))/(4 \[Rho]^2) ((\[Alpha] - x)/\[Alpha] d\[Phi] + (\[Beta] - x)/\[Beta] d\[Psi])^2
```

Where the deltas, rho are defined as:

```
\[CapitalDelta]2 = (\[Alpha] (1 - y))/2 + (\[Beta] (1 + y))/2

\[CapitalDelta]1 = x (\[Alpha] - x) (\[Beta] - x) - \[Mu]

\[Rho] = \[CapitalDelta]2 - x
```

Turns out what I was trying to do was not particularly hard. I am just new to Mathematica and was not using solve as expected. If you take a look at the equations eq1, eq4, eq5 are linear in the d[Tau] d[Phi], d[Psi]. What I did was first solve the system of equations for the above parameters and the apply it to the equation in question.

```
sol = Solve[{eq1, eq4, eq5}, {d\[Tau], d\[Phi], d\[Psi]}
eqH ./ sol
```

The system still struggles with simplification of expression, but it works.

Comment: Might check [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261754/51) for usiroebnerBasis` instead.

Comment: When I run your code I get an error message: "The expression L[\[Tau],x,y,\[Phi],\[Psi],d\[Tau],dx,dy,d\[Phi],d\\[Psi]] involves unknowns in more than one argument, so inverse \functions cannot be used". Moreover, you define the function L with three arguments, but call it with 10 arguments.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full form of the function L. Will also try to use the groebnerBasis.

Comment: First check your variables. With "The full form of the Lagrangian is:" you have different variables at lhs `L[\[Tau]_, x_, y_, \[Phi]_, \[Psi]_, d\[Tau]_, dx_, dy_, d\[Phi]_, d\
\[Psi]_] `

Comment: than at rhs where Variables[rhs] gives you `{d\[Tau], d\[Phi], y, \[Alpha], x, d\[Psi], \[Beta], \
\[CapitalDelta]2, \[Rho], \[CapitalDelta]1, dx, dy} `